# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new in in **vue**, I have this **json**:

[image]

and I have this object in store:

```js
company_profiles: [
  {
    profile: {
      projects: {
        team: {
          teammate: {
            contracts: {}
          }
        }
      }
    },
  }
],
```

I tried to do loop for:

```
<div
  v-for="contract in company_profiles.profile.projects.team.teammate.contracts">
    {{ contract }}
</div>
```

but in console I have this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'teammate')

Answer (score 0):

`company_profiles.profile.projects` is an array, so reading `.team` on it is undefined.

maybe try

```
<div
  v-for="project in company_profiles.profile.projects"
  :key="project.id"
>
  <h3>{{ project.name }}</h3>

  <h4>contract:</h4>
  <pre v-html="project.team?.teammate?.contract" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, if I want to print them above the projects is it possible?

Comment: you can create a computed property `allContracts` that returns all contracts and print them where you like